# Induced homotopy extension property for adjunction spaces.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-extension-property

Let the pair $(X,A)$ have homotopy extension property. Let $B$ be a closed subset of $A$ and consider the map $\varphi : B \longrightarrow Y.$ Then can we say that the pair of adjunction spaces $\left (Y \cup_{\ \varphi} X, Y \cup_{\varphi} A \right )$ also have homotopy extension property? If so, how do I prove that? A small hint will be warmly appreciated at this stage.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: At first, show that for a locally compact Hausdorff space $Z$ and a map $f\colon A\to Y$ we have $(X\cup_f Y)\times Z\cong (X\times Z)\cup_{f\times \text{Id}_Z} (Y\times Z)$. To prove this you need to use $X\cup_f Y$ as a pushout and $(X\sqcup Y)\times Z\xrightarrow{ \text{quotient}\times\text{Id}_Z} (X\cup_f Y)\times Z$ is also a quotient map.  

Now, for $Z=[0,1]$ from the previous lines we have $(X\cup_f Y)\times I$ is pushout of $f\times \text{Id}_Z\colon A\times I\to Y\times I$. Now, use the fact $(X,A)$ has HEP to conclude your result. Let me know if you need a full explanation.

Comment: @Sumanta you are applying Whitehead's theorem to conclude that $q \times \text {id}_Z$ is a quotient map as we are assuming that $Z$ is a locally compact Hausdorff space. Am I right? So what we can conclude at last is that the pair $\left ((X \cup_f Y) \times I, Y \times I \right )$ has HEP.

Comment: @Sumanta Yes that is exactly what is known as Whitehead's theorem.

Comment: But I am unable conclude the required result @Sumanta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Lemma:** For $A\subseteq X$ and $f\colon A\to Y$ we have $(X\cup_f Y)\times Z\cong (X\times Z)\cup_{f\times \text{Id}}(Y\times Z)$ for a locally compact Hausdorff space $Z$.

**Proof:** Consider the maps $i\colon A\hookrightarrow X$, $\kappa\colon X\to X\cup_f Y$, and $\ell\colon Y\to X\cup_f Y$. We need to show $(X\cup_f Y)\times Z$ is the pushout of the inner square below. That is given $G, F$ such that outer square is commutative we have to find $H$. [image]

But, for each $z\in Z$, we have the following diagram as $X\cup_f Y$ is a pushout.
[image]

Now define $H(p,z):=h_z(p)$ for $p\in X\cup_f Y$ and $z\in Z$. And to show $H$ is indeed continuous consider the quotient map $q\colon X\sqcup Y\to X\cup_f Y$. Since $Z$ is LCH $q\times \text{Id}_Z$ is also a quotient map, so we are done by the following diagram.

[image]

---

> Now, we want to show $\ell\colon Y\to X\cup_f Y$ has HEP **for any**
> $f\colon A\subseteq X\to Y$, provided $i\colon A\hookrightarrow X$ has HEP.

That is given $\alpha$ and $\mathcal H$ as in the diagram below such that outer square is commutative, we have to find $\widetilde {\mathcal H}$.

[image]

Note that $i\colon A\hookrightarrow X$ has HEP. So, we have the following:

[image]

Finally, $(X\cup_f Y)\times I$ is a pushout by the previous lemma. So, we have the diagram.

[image]

Check that this $\widetilde {\mathcal H}$ is what we need, i.e., show that it fits into the fourth diagram.

---

So, we have shown $(X\cup_f Y,Y)$ has HEP **for any** $f\colon A\subseteq X\to Y$, provided $A\hookrightarrow X$ has HEP.  Now, to answer your question, note that the composition of two pushout squares is the pushout square. In other words, $ (Y\cup_\varphi A)\cup_\overline \varphi X\cong Y\cup_\varphi X  $, i.e. $Y\cup_\varphi X$ is obtained as adujction space w.r.t. $\overline \varphi\colon A\to  Y\cup_\varphi A$. So, $(X\cup_\varphi Y, A\cup_\varphi Y)$ has HEP.

[image]

Comment: Very nice elaborate answer. Many many thanks. Can you suggest me some reference where we can find arguments using pushouts? I have found it nowhere in Hatcher's book.

Comment: [This book](https://www.elsevier.com/books/lectures-on-homotopy-theory/piccinini/978-0-444-89238-6) is useful for the diagrammatic interpretation of basic classical homotopy theory, but it does not contain any homology or cohomology theory. Also, proving "composition of two pushout squares is again a pushout square" is very straightforward.

Comment: Just a small question. The second diagram what you have drawn to show that the pair $(X \cup_f Y, Y)$ has HEP, there we need to verify whether $(\mathcal H \circ (f \times \text {id})) (a,0) = (\alpha \circ \kappa) (a)$ or in other words $\mathcal H (f(a),0) = (\alpha \circ \kappa) (a).$ Right? Although it is very easy to show. Because from the first diagram it follows that $$\mathcal H(f(a),0) = (\alpha \circ \ell) (f(a) = \alpha (\ell (f(a)) = \alpha (\kappa (a)) = (\alpha \circ \kappa) (a).$$  The penultimate equality follows from the commutativity of the pushout diagram $X \cup_f Y.$

Comment: Is there any free soft copy of this book available online?

Comment: Right. You need to check every diagram is commutative, the small squares, triangles, etc. Keep in mind in $X\cup_f Y$ we have $[a]=\big[f(a)\big]$ for all $a\in A$. I don't know about the freely available soft copy of this book.